# Hackbook Example Hangs and nothing happens on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have followed the instructions on https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin and I have managed to set up the project for HackBook ( iOS ).

My environment is as follows: 
1) xcode: Version 4.5.1 (4G1004) 
2) Phonegap: 2.5 
3) Macbook Pro 64bit. 
4) Facebook SDK 3.2 
5) Target build is iOS5

However, after building and running the project on iOS simulator ( both 5 and 6 ), I am only seeing the "Loading Hackbook" message ( see screen shot ).
[image: Screen Shot 2013-03-16 at 10 43 16 PM]

Than nothing happens.....

The output message I have is as follows:

```
2013-03-16 22:42:44.417 FBConnect[8894:19a03] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2013-03-16 22:42:44.502 FBConnect[8894:19a03] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2013-03-16 22:42:46.692 FBConnect[8894:19a03] Finished load of: file:///Users/eugenely/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/838356B7-F0CE-4A3E-A2F6-1050B1987B05/FBConnect.app/www/index.html
2013-03-16 22:42:46.719 FBConnect[8894:19a03] [LOG] Cordova Facebook Connect plugin initialized successfully.
```

But I do not see anything happening, only the "Loading Hackbook" message.

May I know what could possibly be wrong?

Thank you all for your help!

PS: the Android version works and I have managed to login using the Hackbook example on Android, in case you want to know.

Comment: I have the same issue - I would argue that this isn't particularly localized and the question should be reopened to allow people to potentially answer it

Comment: BTW, I just came back to my iOS6 simulator and it was unhung - was able to log in and all works ... curious